# Holdout method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

How to do 6:4 holdout in python? I tried the following code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =  train_test_split(X,y, training_size=0.6, test_size=0.4)
```

But not sure whether it's right or not.

Comment: well, why don't you just check the size/dim of your results. Looks fine though.

Comment: If I have 100 datapoints, then does it mean that I need to train with 60 datapoints, and test with the other 40?

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the documentation for [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) from scikit-learn.

To set both the size of the training and the test set you need to pass `train_size` (not `training_size` as in your code) and `test_size`.

To use 60% of your data for training and 40% for testing you can use this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.random.rand(100, 2)
y = range(100)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.6, test_size=0.4)
```

You can confirm that for the 100 datapoints used in this example you get a train set size of 60 and a test set size of 40:

```
print(len(X_train), len(X_test))
print(len(y_train), len(y_test))
> 60 40
> 60 40
```